# jquery slide show. Determine which slide AKA Div you are on

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, css

I have a slide show which is made up of a divs. Each Div contains a picture and some html controls. I have a problem where if you click one of the controls, on a slide other than the first one, it will only update the first one. Only thing that changes between the slides is the display which switches from none to block when you go through slide show. Is there any way in jquery to change that slide you are on info without doing a each statements and searching for which class is not hidden? Thank you for any help.

```
 <div class="TheSlide">
      <table>
      <tr>
      <td>

          <div id="divSlideImage"> <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenField1" Value='<%#Eval("ID") %>' />
              <asp:ImageButton runat="server" CssClass="AlbumImageView" Height="480" ID="MainPicture"
                  ImageUrl='<%#Eval("PhotoMainImageURL") %>' AlternateText="Slide not showing properly. Refresh Page." />
                  <div id="pictureTagBorder"></div>
                  </div>
```

```
 <div class="TheSlide">
      <table>
      <tr>
      <td>

          <div id="divSlideImage"> <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenField1" Value='<%#Eval("ID") %>' />
              <asp:ImageButton runat="server" CssClass="AlbumImageView" Height="480" ID="MainPicture"
                  ImageUrl='<%#Eval("PhotoMainImageURL") %>' AlternateText="Slide not showing properly. Refresh Page." />
                  <div id="pictureTagBorder"></div>
                  </div>
```

I am trying to tag on this class to the picture when user clicks on control, but it will only do this script on the first slide.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            var top = y - 232;
            var left = x - 145;
            $('#pictureTagBorder').css({ top:top , left: left });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pictureTagBorder` isn't a class, it's an `id` attribute. Your `id` attributes **must** be unique on each page and I'm guessing that you have multiple elements with `id="pictureTagBorder"` and `id="divSlideImage"` (and possibly others) so your HTML is invalid. An id selector, such as `#pictureTagBorder`, will match at most one element and you say that

> it will only do this script on the first slide

so your problem is that you're using `id` attributes when you should be using CSS classes to identify your slide elements.